# The equation of a curve

Tags: curves, plane-curves

I need to write the equation of a curve which exactly goes throw point points:

$$\left(0,\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-1\right),\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}\right),\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{88}{63}\right),\left(1,\frac{3}{4}\right)$$
and the same values for negative arguments, i. e.

$$\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3}\right),\left(-\frac{3}{4},\frac{2\pi}{3}-\frac{88}{63}\right),\left(-1,\frac{3}{4}\right).$$

Comment: There are uncountably many smooth curves passing through your seven points.

Comment: I assume you want an equation of a parabola that goes through these points with the equation $y = ax^2 + bx + c$? Just use the points and find the values of $a$ and $b$. $c$ is $\frac {π^2}6 - 1$ if you did indeed ask for a parabola.

Comment: **Hint:** The equation (if it is indeed a parabola) should be $y - \frac {π^2}6 + 1 = kx^2$. Try inputting some values to find the value of $k$ and check if it is right.

Comment: Someone has shown that it is impossible in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2587801/99914) @MohammadZuhairKhan

Comment: @JohnMa Yes even I have achieved the same result. However I have achieved an equation which provides fairly close answers.

Comment: The parabola doesn't pass through the point $(1,\frac{3}{4})$. So, if there are uncountably many smooth curves passing seven points, how to find at least one?

Comment: There are uncountably many curves that is not a parabola. @MariannaKalwat